# SwiftUI Alert shown once

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My app consumes few API endpoints to fetch data, that is managed by respective ViewModels.

For example, this ViewModel fetch the languages

```swift
class LanguageViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    @Published private(set) var languages: [LanguageItem]?
    @Published private(set) var error: Error?

    func get() {
        APIService.fetchData()
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] value in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                if case let .failure(error) = value {
                    self.error = error
                }

            }, receiveValue: { (data: [LanguageItem]) in
                self.languages = data

            })
            .store(in: &self.subscriptions)
    }
}
```

and so on.

Now for the main UI

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var languageViewModel = LanguageViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        let hasError = Binding<Bool>(
            get: { self.languageViewModel.error != nil },
            set: { _ in }
        )

        Button(action: {
            self.languageViewModel.get()
        }) {
            Text("Hello, World")
        }
        .alert(isPresented: hasError) {
            let message = self.languageViewModel.error?.description

            return Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(message ?? ""), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
    }
}
```

If somehow the API call fails on clicking the button, the first and only first time the alert is shown, then on subsequent clicks does not appear.

Placing a breakpoint on `.alert` show that the code is running correctly, just not showing again.

Please send help!!

Comment: why don't you have a `@Publisher` variable in the `LanguageViewModel` to pass as a `@Binding` variable instead? See [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126796)

Comment: Did you reset error to nil after alert is closed?

Comment: You doesn't seem to reset the error state anywhere. You could set a closure in the setter of the binding which is defined in the view model and which sets your error to nil, for example `set: { _ in  self.languageViewModel.dismiss() }`

Comment: That's a crazy, non-standard `Binding` you have there. As others have said, better having `hasError` as a published property in the view model.

Comment: Hello all, and I'm really sorry for the delay. Again, you guys were right. Can @Asperi submit an answer for marking it completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On alert dismiss button action reset error back to nil, like:

```
.alert(isPresented: hasError) {
    let message = self.languageViewModel.error?.description

    return Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(message ?? ""), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")) {
       self.languageViewModel.error = nil    // << here !!
    })
}
```